# PHP <BR> After 2 loops

Tags: php, loops

I wanted to add `<br>` after every 2 loops.

The loop will run 8 times and after every 2 loops I want to add `<br>`

Can anyone help?

The loop will look like this:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result2 )) {

}
```

Comment: I actually don't have a clue of how it works so I didn't try. I tried looking for examples online but didn't find any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$c=0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result2 )) {
     //PUSH YOUR CODE
     $c++;
     if($c%2==0)
         echo "<br/>";
}
```

Comment: then dont forget do mark the answer as correct by clicking the small tick mark on the left to this answer...

Comment: I am, don't worry. Just waiting for the timer to let me.

Comment: Oh well it prints br on every second record not after every 2 records but I guess thats what OP wanted but didn't phrase it correctly.

Answer (score 5):

Notice: this isn't a pretty good syntax. If you want to achive some style with TD rows you could use new css selector: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-nthchild

```
$i=0;
for(;;) {
  $i++;

  if ($i%2==0)
    echo '<br>';

}
```

Comment: @yes123 - Horrible syntax - you should at least try, no matter how easy you think the answer is.

Comment: I don't even understand loops to well, just started understanding them better.

Comment: @R2-Bacca: I see almost no differences with your answered copied from mine

Comment: @yes123 - let me clarify - the syntax is horrible for someone who is clearly a beginner... fit your answer to you audience. I'm not takinng a personal shot at you, just an observation that the code you posted is difficult to read. And mine is different... not copied from yours. You just beat me to it :-)

Comment: This is an infinite loop. How is it helpful?

Comment: @DavidStockton: Of course it was just to show him how to do it. HE didn't mentioned of while ..mysql_fetch before

Answer (score 0):

Inside your loop:

```
$i = 0;
while(whatever){
    if($i % 2 == 0){
        echo '<br/>';
    }
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: @JamesHam add a counter for your loop

Comment: Are you using a for, foreach or while loop?

Comment: While and how do I add a counter to it?

Comment: Edited answer to use a while loop instead